# Is Blender suitable, or perhaps overkill, for making 2d graphic of water flowing in pipe?

Tags: modeling

I'm in the market for a free or inexpensive program that will help me create a graphic of water flowing through pipes (2D is OK, and preferred at this point). Would Blender be suitable for this, or would it be overkill in view of Blender's reportedly steep learning curve?

Comment: Do you mean a 2D scene or a 2D output? Normally, Blender's output is 2D. Also, it's not much of a market if it's free :P

Comment: Yes doing something like that would be very easy to do in blender using  fluid simulation.

Comment: see: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-fluid-simulator/

Comment: It is entirely possible and not too difficult. Free alternatives would be 2D animation packages like Synfig Studio http://www.synfig.org/cms/ or Krita https://krita.org/en/ (recently acquired animation features). I've never used them so I can't really vouch for them

Comment: ....  My requirements are probably best demonstrated by the water flow in this public relations cartoon on water treatment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldz29NqwK78

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible to create a 2D graphic like this in Blender. Perhaps it's a bit much, but Blender is pretty easy to use for this kind of stuff. Here's an animation I whipped up in Blender of something like what I think you're describing:
[image]

Simply switch the render engine to cycles in a new scene, align the camera to front view (NUMPAD 1 and then ctrl-alt-NUMPAD 0) and add in shapes such as planes and make sure to use emission materials for everything. Use the displace modifier with a texture and keyframe the size values at frames 0 and 70 to be 0.25 and 0.7.